# Importing GregorianCalendar in (nifi ecmascript processor) groovy

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi

How can I use GregorianCalendar?
I tried this inside my (executeScript processor script) but it throws exception

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
```

Comment: What's ecmascript got to do with Groovy and Java?

Comment: I have no idea, ecmascript  look like  javasscriprt and  groovy is based on java

Answer (score 1):

```
var GregorianCalendar = Java.type("java.util.GregorianCalendar");
```

check `javascript` examples here:

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75545/executescript-cookbook-part-2.html

but i think you don't need it because ecmascript/javascript has own `Date` class that allows you to work with dates...